# Dependency Injection: How to define constructor when framework class gets overwritten

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I've recently created a module for Magento 2 which depends on various Magento framework classes through dependency injection like so:

```
// Vendor\Module\Helper\Debug
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Message $message,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport $transport,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Config $configHelper
) {
    ...
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

This worked well until a third party module was installed that overrides the Message and Transport Framework classes in their di.xml:

```
<preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message" type="OtherVendor\Module\Model\Message"/>
<preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport" type="OtherVendor\Module\Model\Transport"/>
```

Now my Module returns the following error

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Vendor\Module\Helper\Debug::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Mail\Message, instance of OtherVendor\Module\Model\Message given
```

I've already tried deleting the `var/generation` folder, as well as refreshing and subsequently disabling the Magento cache.

What can I do to change my constructor so that it works either way? So by using either the `Magento\Framework\Mail\Message` core class or the override class by the third-party module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface` interface in yours `__construct` method. If someone did rewrite of the class `Magento\Framework\Mail\Message`, then it shall implement this interface, but isn't obliged to extend a base class.

```
// Vendor\Module\Helper\Debug
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface $transport,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Config $configHelper
) {
    ...
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

You can [read more info here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) I think third-party module developers make a low-quality rewrite and they don't think about how their module will works with another modules. In my opinion they should extend base class in their rewrite-class.

Comment: This works for me while retaining functionality as well. Although I'm not entirely satisfied, knowing that my code can break anytime if I inject the wrong Magento base class. Or does this mean I should only ever inject interface type objects?

Comment: @sduif You can read more info [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) I think third-party module developers make a low-quality rewrite and they don't think about how their module will works with another modules. In my opinion they should extend base class in their rewrite-class.

Comment: Thanks, looks like in my case I should've read up some more on Newable/non-injectable. In my case the injection wasn't even needed since I could just create new instances of `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message` and `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport` when required.

Comment: @sduif I hope that means you're injecting `\Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory` and `\Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory $transportFactory` instead then, not getting them from `ObjectManager`. :)